# Encountered NoMethodError in one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a prototype of a chat room system. Specifically, users can create a "room" first, and then add "messages" from the room. However, when I increment the message I get a NoMethodError with the message `` undefined method `room' for #<Message:0x00007fcaa80530a0> ``, where it goes wrong is `<%= form_with(model: [ @message.room, @message ]) do |form| %>`. I'm not sure what I'm missing or writing wrong.

This is the View (new.html.erb)

```
<h1>New Message</h1>

<%= form_with(model: [ @message.room, @message ]) do |form| %>
  <div class = "field">
    <%= form.text_field :content %>
    <%= form.submit "Send" %>
  </div>
<% end%>

<%= link_to 'Back', @message.room %>
```

This is the MessagesController

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_room, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @message = @room.messages.new
  end

  def create
    @message = @room.messages.create!(message_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to @room}
    end
  end

private
  def set_room
    @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:content)
  end

end
```

The RoomsController was created by Scaffold.

This is model Message

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message
end
```

This is the model Room

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
end
```

Comment: it should be `belongs_to :room` in messages model

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy Do you know what ```(model: [ @message.room, @message ])``` means? here is usually path